# Java Junit4: assertEquals for ArrayList<Double> with single precision expected values

Tags: java, arraylist, junit, junit4, precision

I'm writing a JUnit test for a Java variable that is `ArrayList<Double>`. The complication is that my expected values are single precision whereas Java's `Double` is double precision. So doing `assertEquals(expected_array_list, actual_array_list)` does not pass due to precision errors.

My work-around is to iterate over all the elements and `assertEquals` each pair of doubles, setting the `epsilon` value to an appropriate value. Is there a method of setting the `epsilon` for the entire `ArrayList`, instead of having to decompose it into its elements?

Comment: You could implement an own method which gets the expected double and the actual double value. Then you can proceed the values in this method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JUnit 4.6 and above has a convenience method [`assertArrayEquals(double[] expected, double[] actual, double delta)`](http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/latest/org/junit/Assert.html#assertArrayEquals(double%5B%5D%2C%20double%5B%5D%2C%20double)) method (with an overloaded variant for a `String` message, as per the norm). In Java 8, you could convert those `List`s to primitive arrays pretty easily and just use it:

```
double delta = 0.05; // or any other reasonable value
double[] expectedArray = 
    expectedList.stream().mapToDouble(Double::doubleValue).toArray();
double[] actualArray = 
    actualList.stream().mapToDouble(Double::doubleValue).toArray();
assertArrayEqulas(expectedArray, actualArray, delta);
```

Comment: @RoiEX you Sir, are [almost] correct. After giving it a second look, I see this method was added in JUnit 4.6 (introduced by commit 41cbbf7e228b8f7908e672a79863ff970316b120). Not sure why I originally missed it though. I was probably looking at outdated Javadoc, shame on me. I've edited my answer with this information.

Comment: Btw it's probably easier to do `expectedList.toArray(new double[expectedList.size()])` to get an array of a list

Comment: Oh my bad... The Version I checked was 4.12 and not 4.1 :D

Comment: @RoiEX no - we're trying to convert a list of `java.lang.Double` to an array of primitive `double`s. This code doesn't even compile.

Comment: Ok missed that part

Comment: Thanks very much for your comments, I thought there must be a better way of doing it! :)